# Login text appears two times in html submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Login page Login button text appears two times,

May be this is a issue of jquery mobile,

HTML CODE:

```
<form>
<div class="submit_button" data-ajax="false">
<input type="submit" class="login" value="login" />
</div>
</form>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.submit_button
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

.login
    {
        float:none;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        padding: 2% 20% 2% 20%;
        background: #33B5E5;
        border: none;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: remove value="login" in the code

Comment: Try this - <input type="submit" class="login">login</input>

Comment: Upgrading jQuery mobile fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/eeLq8/

Comment: @user3004356 inputs are void elements

Comment: @user3004356 i have tried this code already,then inside the button submit comes,next line login comes,but outside login should not come..

Comment: check this its work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/hqMyv/

Comment: @A.Wolff can you say the upgraded version which i needed for this issue.

Comment: @user1153551 here jquery is not defined,so working fine.

Comment: try inspector element to find error.

Comment: @KesaVan has been 'fixed' in jQuery Mobile 1.2.0

Comment: .ui-btn-text{display:none;}

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot for any reason upgrade to at least jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, you could still use following workaround:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HZWF/)

```
$('.login:submit').prev('.ui-btn-inner').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery mobile,and use class "login" into input type text so it because of class login it show one "login" text and you are using one more text "login" by adding value attribute value="login"
so you should remove value field

Comment: if i remove value ,then submit will come,but i need only login as text inside the button

Comment: Do you need class="login" in your form?
if not then please try reverse.